# I can't position the text inside the borders

Tags: html, css, sass

[image]

Well I tried to put borders so I can have a button but when I do that the text moves?

How do I center the text in the y axis direction so it's inline like inline with other nav elements. You can see what I mean in the picture above.

```css
#freebook{
    width: auto;
    height: 45px;
    box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,0.25) 0 2px 5px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding-top: -10px;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-family: nunito;
    border-radius: 6px;
    color: #3e8ef7 !important;
    background-color: #dfebef;
    border: #3e8ef7 2px solid;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**

Comment: If you click [edit] and the "edit this snippet" link, you can literally copy and paste the code from CodePen into the snippet editor. Only you can do it since you are the copyright holder.

Comment: ok I will do it next time, thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

edit the css as below, the trick is remove the padding and add the line-height

```css
#freebook{
    width: auto;
    height: 45px;
    
    line-height:1;
    
    box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,0.25) 0 2px 5px;
    text-align: center;
   
    
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-family: nunito;
    border-radius: 6px;
    color: #3e8ef7 !important;
    background-color: #dfebef;
    border: #3e8ef7 2px solid;
}
```

```html
<button id="freebook" >some text</button>
```

Comment: Answers which explain what code was changed and why are downvoted less often than those that just show changed code.